# mac os x python different version uninstalling

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

Lately when I typed "python" in Terminal i saw that much python versions:
[That much options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRDJC.png)

I wanted only 3.8 installed so I'm trying to uninstall everything else

I had these 2 paths where python was installed:

1. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions (3.4, 3.5, 3.8)`
2. `/Library/Python (2.7)`

In my Application directory I have only Python 3.8, so i moved 3.4 and 3.5 folders to Trash
Then the list of  version became smaller

[Only 2.7 and 3.8 Python left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U84t6.png)

When I move /Library/Python (2.7) nothing seems to happen, I continue to see 2.7 in Terminal
So the question is: how do I remove Python 2.7?